# Detect round bracket, both open and close

Tags: c++, regex

I need to break a expression such as `"(a+b*9      )-10"` to extract/detect `(` and `)`.

This is what I have now but either case doesn't work.

```
const regex Parser::rxOpenBracket = regex("^\\s*[(]\\s*$");

const regex Parser::rxCloseBracket = regex("^\\s*([)])\\s*$");
```

Some help will be good. thanks!

Comment: Don't `\(` and `\)` work?

Comment: You've tagged this c++, could you show your code?

Comment: const regex Parser::rxOpenBracket = regex("^\\s*[\(]\\s*$");
const regex Parser::rxCloseBracket = regex("^\\s*([\)])\\s*$");

this is wad i try currently. either case doesnt work.

Comment: @user1806698 It's possible to edit questions on Stack Overflow. Please edit the code in (sufficiently formatted) instead of posting it as a comment.

Comment: alright, changed. thanks for guidance.

Comment: Please also note the "sufficiently formatted" part in my comment. I did the formatting for you this time, try to do it yourself in the future.

Comment: I'm a great fan of regular expressions, but they seem overkill here.  `std::find` or `std::find_if` should be all you need.

Comment: @JamesKanze, yup.  `RegEx` solutions are the C++ go-to answers like LINQ is the C# go-to response without anyone ever considering overkill.

Comment: @Moo-Juice Then again, if the OP wants to replace the parentheses or split on them, regex would be _just_ right.

Answer (score 3):

Or you could write it:

```
const regex Parser::bracketPair = regex("\\(.+?\\)");
```

The expressions translates like this:

```
\(.+?\)
\( => The opening bracket (escaped as ( would indicate a group in regex)
.  => Any character
*  => Zero or more times (referring to the .)
?  => Lazy, stop as soon as possible (referring to the *)
\) => End bracket, also escaped
```

By using this you would only find hits that starts with an opening bracket, followed by none or any number of characters until a closing bracket is found.

For instance `(hello world)` would be handled, but `)hello world(` would be ignored

Comment: The compile should throw some warning for `\(`, since it is not a valid escape sequence, and `\(` can be interpreted as `(` by the compiler (the specs says implementation-defined). Note that I am not talking about the regex, but about the string literal.

Comment: Yes, correct you are. You would need to escape the escape slashes in the string. `"\\(.+?\\)"`. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 2):

`\s` in a regex matches whitespace, `^` matches the start of the string and `$` matches the end. So in effect, your regexes would only match strings containing a single opening/closing parenthesis, optionally preceded/followed by whitespace. No other characters allowed.

If you're really looking for the parenthesis characters only, regexes are way overkill. Just use [`std::string::find_first_of()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of):

```
std::string data("(a+b*9 )-10");

for (std::size_t idx = data.find_first_of("()"); idx != data.npos; idx = data.find_first_of("()", idx + 1))
{
  //idx now holds the index of a parenthesis:
  assert(data[idx] == '(' || data[idx] == ')');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the anchors `^`  and `$`:

```
const regex Parser::rxOpenBracket = regex("\\s*[(]\\s*");
const regex Parser::rxCloseBracket = regex("\\s*([)])\\s*");
```

Answer (score 1):

`^` and `$` are anchors for the start and the end of the line. If you just want to find out if there's *any* parenthesis *at all*, without it necessarily being at the start or the end of the line, you can leave those out.

Also, since you match white space of length 0 or more, unless you're matching to remove it (replacing it with an empty string), you can leave that out as well.

That leaves you with

```
const regex Parser::rxOpenBracket = regex("\\(");

const regex Parser::rxCloseBracket = regex("\\)");
```

Or, if you prefer,

```
const regex Parser::rxOpenBracket = regex("[(]");

const regex Parser::rxCloseBracket = regex("[)]");
```